# Django ORM filter in multiple columns

Tags: filter, orm, django-filters

I'm new to Django and Web frameworks. 
I have a question regarding Django ORM Filter querying

Order is a Table which references to another table named Show. Show has 3 managers say manager, manager_2, manager_3.

Now I want to pick the Orders, whose users are either of these 3 managers. 
How do i do that. 
I'm looking for some thing like this:

```
Order.objects.filter(    
    order_cancelled__isnull = True,
    (show__manager = user || show_manager_2 = user || show_manager_3 = user))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.

Can use Q

```
from django.models import Q  

Order.objects.filter(
    Q(show__manager = user) | Q(show_manager_2 = user) | Q(show_manager_3 = user),
    order_cancelled__isnull = True
)
```